# Magento Media wysiwyg Error

Tags: error, wysiwyg, media

It was caused because the last magento  update does not allow spaces in the image name in this folder `public_html/pub/media/wysiwyg`
We cleared spaces in image urlsbut still  had a problem.
Because of the error I tried to see the folder in admin using a filter show 300 which caused a time out, I could not clear using my user profile, I did try increasing session limit in admin but decided against increasing by a lot so I created a new user using the default filter. That worked
To sum up clear the spaces and dont use more than 32 per page in filters.